# Con statement in raster calculator ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have four rasters (A, B, C, D) based on which my classification works. The con statement I have been using is posted below.

My problem is when A_01 is 2. Area when A=2, if value of B is less than 3, it categorizes the ares under 2, but when B is between 3 and 12, and value for C is exactly 0.24, it is categorizing the area under 3.

For eg: any area where A=2, B=3.56 and C=0.24, I assume it should fall under category 2, since value for B is less than 12 and C is exactly 0.24, but it is being categorized as 3. Can anybody help me figure the error in this statement?

```
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 1) & ("%B_01.tif%" > 12), 3, 
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 1) & ("%B_01.tif%" <= 12), 4,
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 1) & ("%D_01.tif%" == 1), 4,
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 2) & ("%B_01.tif%" <= 12) & ("%C_01.tif%" >= 0.24), 2, 
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 2) & ("%B_01.tif%" > 12), 2, 
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 2) & ("%B_01.tif%" >= 3) & ("%B.tif%" <= 12) & ("%C_01.tif%" < 0.24), 3, 
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 2) & ("%B_01.tif%" < 3) & ("%C_01.tif%" < 0.24), 4, 
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 2) & ("%D_01.tif%" == 1), 4, 
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 3) & ("%D_01.tif%" == 0), 2, 
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 3) & ("%D_01.tif%" == 1), 4, 
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 4) & ("%D_01.tif%" == 0), 1, 
Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 4) & ("%D_01.tif%" == 1), 4))))))))))))
```

Comment: These nested Cons always get too messy to make sense of. How do you feel about arcpy/numpy?

Comment: You've got a "%B.tif%" in there. Should that be "%B_01.tif%"?

Comment: Thanks, It is B_01.tif, just got a typo error when I was changing the name of my raster to B.

Comment: Another check you should do to make sure its not the data but the logic that is the problem. Try running Con(("%A_01.tif%" == 2) & ("%B_01.tif%" <= 12) & ("%C_01.tif%" >= 0.24), 2, 0) by itself. If it is processing correctly you'll get 2's where you want and 0 everywhere else, so you have confidence that your data is correct and it's not some weird rounding issue?

Comment: When I run that single line or the whole statement, it does give me category 2 for all areas where value of C_01 is more than 0.24, but not exactly 0.24.

Comment: Seeing as these are integer rasters (do IsNull c<0.24 to get an integer of C) why not combine http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000007r000000 them, add a field and use a field calculation instead, an advanced field calculation with nested elif statements has to be better (and more readable) than nested Con statements. Each Con needs to be evaluated to a temporary raster, which adds processing time and space, combine and field calc would only be one SA operation and there's a good chance the results tab would tell you where any logic faults are in an error message.

Answer (score 1):

- Reclass A into 1, 2, 4, 8
- Reclass B into 16, 32, 64
- Reclass C into 128, 256
- Reclass D into 512, 1024

Cell statistics(SUM) will give you few unique combinations, easy for final reclass, unless you'd like to use Combine

Comment: +1 This is good advice, in part because it separates the problem cleanly into two parts: converting four rasters into categories and then combining those categories logically.  The attempt in the OP to do it all at once leads to multiply redundant execution and increases the possibility of inconsistencies and errors (one tiny typo, undetected, could screw everything up).