# Classify a raster into three classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

Bellow there is a raster with range from ~0 to ~0.99. I have created the following formula using raster calculator `(("Soil_Moisture_Index")>=0.3)&("Soil_Moisture_Index")<=0.5))` in order to show values inside [0.3,0.5] (2nd image). I would like to also include values "<0.3" and ">0.5" but I can't do it using raster calculator. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess that you're looking for this tools: [Reclassify](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm)

Comment: @obchardon the problem using this tool is that, I can't express "<" and ">" alone. It only gives me ">=" and "<=" choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want three output categories:

1. "< 0.3"
2. ">=0.3 and <= 0.5"
3. "> 0.5"

There are two potential tools you can use - [Reclassify](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm) and [Raster Calculator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/raster-calculator.htm).

**Option 1: Reclassify**

Looking at the text of [Reclassify](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm):

"If a range of values is to be reclassed, the ranges should not overlap except at the boundary of two input ranges. Where overlapping occurs, the higher end of the lower input range is inclusive, and the lower end of the higher input range is exclusive.

For example, if two ranges are specified, such as reclassifying values 1 to 5 as 100 and values 5 to 10 as 200, an input value less than or equal to 5 will be assigned the value 100 in the output, and an input value that is larger than 5, such as 5.01, will be assigned to 200."

The problem is that first junction around 0.3. To format you request in the format Reclassify uses use the following categories:

1. "<= 0.299999" (double check appropriate number of decimals)
2. ">0.299999 and <= 0.5"
3. "> 0.5"

**Option 2: Raster Calculator**

Use a series of nested conditional statements, like the poster uses in [Con statement in raster calculator ArcGIS 10.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183155/con-statement-in-raster-calculator-arcgis-10-3?rq=1). Instead of dealing with the extra complication of the AND statement for the middle category, just make that category the default "else" option. Something like:

Con(raster < 0.3, LowestCategoryValue, Con(raster > 0.5, HighestCategoryValue, MediumCategoryValue))